# How to Scroll/Follow Menu with CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, menu

How to Scroll/Follow Menu with CSS and Javascript?

I am testing a scroll/follow menu on this page, http://www.pablitogreco.com/xtango/#x. The menu exists inside a modal window. After studying numerous examples from stackoverflow this is the one that came closer:

http://jsfiddle.net/c0pnrvc6/

But **scrolling up has several flaws**, and I think I am missing a lot. I have done extensive research on Stackoverflow and other platforms, and tried many implementations. Please, can you assist with my below code, and point me to the right direction?

Html

```
<div class=scroller>Xtango</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroller {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.68);
z-index: 1}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
$('.scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop()); } });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -1 instead of 0.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > -1) {
    $('.scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
  }
});
```

Comment: it worked so well back then! I used it to another project recently.